Flutter TextEditingController not setting textbox contents on MacBook M1
I have a simple textbox with a TextEditingController defined like this:
final _detailInputController = TextEditingController();

It is assigned properly to the textbox with:
controller: _detailInputController,

I am using the following simple code to set the content of the text box when the user selects a value from a separate list:
  onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      _detailInputController.text = thisDetail;
    });
  },

It works perfectly in Android and iOS, but on a MacBook M1 the code does nothing. The rest of the app works fine on the MacBook.
Any ideas why this isn't working in the MacBook or how to fix it? Thank you.
